# User specific stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I have a website where a user chooses a template of their choice for their web page.

Once they've selected the template, I want them to be able to change some of the styles such as the font colour etc?

Is there a way I could do this?

I thought of perhaps storing the user specified stuff in a field in a database and then retrieve it and display as internal CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a user.css (initially empty) for each user and then add data provided by user with !important override.

Comment: How would I write the new CSS into the user.css file dynamically?

Comment: while selecting theme user is triggering an event.right?catch the data and parse it into user.css.just like a submit action.but instaed of writing it in DB,it will write it o css

Comment: How would I parse it using asp.net?

Comment: Would I use the StreamWriter feature of ASP.NET?

Comment: not sure about asp.net,but catching data from user and parsing, is the most basic thing you need.just think about a form,how you are storing the data and implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

It is possible. But you will have to rely on Javascript to add the stylesheet, url selected.

Assuming you would be using a link to change the theme, using jQuery, you would do

```
$('#red').click(function (){
   $('#linktagid').attr('href','user_red.css');
});
```